# error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/eslint-config-pretttier: Not found"

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

yarn add -D prettier eslint-plugin-prettier eslint-config-pretttier error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/eslint-config-pretttier: Not found". It was.

Answer (score 0):

@sato desu, You miss-spelled the dependency

try this command `yarn add -D prettier eslint-plugin-prettier eslint-config-prettier`